# Is an answer or comment with indirect slang considered rude / abusive / offensive for this site?

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-answer, scope, etiquette

To my question, a user posted below answer:

> I'm in the UK. If any employer suggested that here, you would be asked *"are you completely **bonkers**?"* Your concerns about my leisure would be answered with *"what I do in my free time is none of your **f---ing** business"*. This **seems rude**, but any employer here trying this would be considered extremely rude and only getting what they deserve. ...

Here the answerer is trying to put forth a possible agitated reaction. But it's more explicit and I feel that going to such an extent is not required.
I flagged this answer, but the moderator declined it.

So I wanted to know why is it not considered as rude?

[**Note**: Haven't put the link to the original post, as I don't want its voting pattern to influence this post. Hoping for a neutral response.]

Answer (score 5):

I was the moderator who declined your flag. I reviewed the flagged answer and it's clear in my view that the poster was giving an example the sort of response the statements you posit management making in the question would receive in the context of their country. Presumably with the intent of demonstrating to you that those statements would be considered rude.

The "rudeness" in the answer appeared not to be directed at you *personally* in the same way the "rude" statements in the question weren't aimed at those reading your question, the profanity was appropriately self-censored by the author of the answer, and taking these things into account I saw nothing actionable and declined the flag. The reverse holds - if someone were to flag your question as Rude/Abusive on the basis of the "rude" statements that answer was "responding" to I'd decline that too.

Comment: Whether the rudeness is directed towards me or not is irrelevant. If the answer contains such implicit or explicit language, it deserves to be moderated in an appropriate way. What about *"Be polite"* policy of stack exchange? There can be several ways countrymen can respond to a given situation. Do you think it's fair, if people start writing literals in a coded way? I hope like other users, a Mod must not get carried away by the nature of the question.

Comment: Again, I see nothing actionable or against the CoC in the post you flagged, nor do I see anything in violation of the spirit of "Be Nice". I do not believe that that the poster was attempting to veil an attack on you in this  case and I do believe I've taken the appropriate moderation action in declining the flag.

Comment: Molehill, meet mountain

Answer (score 3):

I would have declined the flag for the same reasons as Moto.

We do have a 'be nice' policy, we also have 'assume good intentions'. They work together well for a multi-cultural site where ways of expression can differ widely and misunderstandings can happen.

Comment: You are indirectly allowing users to use expletives directed towards someone with '*' in between to hide the phrase and then defend this by implying that this is how XYZ would have responded. Are the mods here following a different "Be Nice" policy? Refer [_Don't be a jerk -- Bigotry_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/163449). This should supersede _"assume good intention"_.

Comment: I interpret things my own way, perhaps it's a cultural difference.

Comment: Answerer posted: *I'm in the UK. If any employer suggested that here, ... would be answered with "... none of your **f---ing** business"*. Under that reply, if someone posts a comment such as: *"If you answered like that, then some employers may politely ask you to "get the f---k off & never show your a-- again!"*. Would that be appropriate and acceptable as per your standard?

Comment: I'd probably delete that comment if people complained, but comments are not supposed to be permanent, I delete comments just because they take up too much room sometimes. If you're asking if I personally would be offended, then no... English profanity means little to me in terms of being offended. In this case it's not even profanity...just a bunch of hyphens and it's not even directed at me.